# CONCAT return BOLB at server side

Tags: mysql, concatenation

Sample original value of inputDate

```
inputDate
2013-11-19
2013-11-20
2013-11-22
2013-12-04
```

i want the result to be return in:

```
Nov-2013
Nov-2013
Nov-2013
Dec-2013
```

im using the query as below to get the result.

```
SELECT CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(inputDate, '%b'), '-' , YEAR(inpuDate)) AS entryDate FROM table
```

- datatype of inputDate is 'Date'
- running at local has no problem
- running at server result return "BLOB".

how to show the result at server side? i double check the datatype, and restore the data from server to my local. nothing helped.
there is no 'NULL' value inside this field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not just do (`%Y` will give you the year part):

```
select DATE_FORMAT(inputDate, '%b-%Y') AS entryDate from `table`
```